# Javascript: getting wrong dates of current weeks

Tags: javascript

I want to get all the seven dates (Monday to Sunday) from the current week. The below code is working well.

```
let curr = new Date(); // today's date is: 15th April 2020
let week = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
    let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i;
    let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    week.push(day);
}
console.log(week); // output: ["2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-19"]
```

However, assume the current date is 19th April 2020. Then the code is returning the wrong dates.

```
let curr = new Date('2020-04-19'); // today's date is: 19th April 2020
let week = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
 let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i;
 let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
    week.push(day);
 }
console.log(week); // output: ["2020-04-20", "2020-04-21", "2020-04-22", "2020-04-23", "2020-04-24", "2020-04-25", "2020-04-26"]
```

It should return the output like 
`["2020-04-13", "2020-04-14", "2020-04-15", "2020-04-16", "2020-04-17", "2020-04-18", "2020-04-19"]`

Comment: You should iterate from 0 - 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like if `curr` falls on a Sunday, you want to jump back an entire week, so I would change this line:

```
let first = curr.getDate() - curr.getDay() + i;
```

to:

```
let first = curr.getDate() - ( curr.getDay() ? curr.getDay() : 7 ) + i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns 0 for Sunday, but your code requires 7 to find the preceding Monday, you just need to allow for that and adjust when required:

```js
let curr = new Date('2020-04-19'); // today's date is: 19th April 2020
let week = []
for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  let dow = curr.getDay();
  if (!dow) dow = 7;
  let first = curr.getDate() - dow + i;
  let day = new Date(curr.setDate(first)).toISOString().slice(0, 10)
  week.push(day);
}
console.log(week);
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

For Sundays, getDay() will return 0, not 7.